# Compare LastLoginDate of user from multiple DC's

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I got 2 DCs and need to get a list of all my users that haven't logged in for X days. I got a PS script that looks at the user his last logon date on the domain and then filters and export the users that haven't logged on for the X days.

PowerShell script:

```
$AmountDays = 30
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Enabled, LastLogonDate |
    ? {
        $_.LastLogonDate -ne $null -and
        $_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$AmountDays)
    } |
    sort LastLogonDate |
    Select Name,LastLogonDate |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\LastLogonUser.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is my DC's have different LastLogonDates of that same user. 
So if I run my script on DC1 for example he thinks the user haven't logged in for over 20 days, but when i run it on DC2 he logged in yesterday.

Is there a way to check the LastLogonDate of the same user from both DC's and take the most recent one, so I can check the result of the compare if the user haven't logged in for X days?

---

I have edited my code so it uses a foreach loop to go through my DCs and find my users. But I think it stops after he went through the first one. Because if I run a simple code to check if he can find both DCs he views them both. But when I run my code and export the result, it only shows each member ones and not all the LastLogonDates are correct.

New Script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $AmountDays = 0

  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  {
     Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Enabled, LastLogonDate | ? { `
($_.LastLogonDate -NE $NULL -AND $_.LastLogonDate -LT (Get-
Date).AddDays(-$AmountDays)) } |
sort LastLogonDate | Select Name,LastLogonDate |
Export-Csv C:\temp\LastLogonUser.csv -NoTypeInformation 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LastLogonDate` is a `DateTime` object, try to convert it first to your local time using the [ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

So try:

```
Get-ADUser [...] -Properties LastLogonDate | 
? { $_.LastLogonDate -and $_.LastLogonDate.ToLocalTime() -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30)}
```

Also, Make sure to sync the DC's Clock, To validate it use the `Net Time \\YouDcName` command

Answer (score 0):

I could actually use some help with the question asked as well because I need to modify a report that I make to do a comparison against 16 DC's and 1200 Computer accounts to find the last logon and passwordlastset

This is logic that I have used for a smaller set of data but I don't think it will be efficient with ~20,000 rows of data to find accurate info. It would be slow.

```
$Users = @(
"User1"
"User2"
)
$DomainControllers = @(
"DC1"
"DC2"
)

Foreach ($User in $Users){

    Foreach ($Controller in $DomainControllers){

        $Data = Get-ADUser $User -Properties "LastLogonDate" -Server $Controller | Select LastLogonData

    }    
    $Data = $null
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271763/get-aduser-across-domains-best-practices Someone asked a similar question luckily enough which with simplify part of it. I haven't posted a question yet because I am not ready to tackle everything that project is going to involve

Answer (score 0):

That is what [`LastLogonTimestamp`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/) was invented for, given that a value from 1 or 2 weeks ago is sufficient for your needs. If not you'll have to query all domain controllers and pick the most recent value.

```
Get-ADDomainController | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server $_ -Properties Enabled, LastLogonDate | Where-Object {
        # ...
    } | Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate
} | Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name, @{n='LastLogon';e={
    $_.Group |
        Sort-Object LastLogonDate |
        Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand LastLogonDate
}
```

Comment: When going through each DC does powershell filters out duplicates automatically? I had a script that did that but the result was no duplicate users even if they have LastLoginDate on both DCs, so only one LastLoginDate was shown that wasn't always accurate to the real LastLoginDate.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't eliminate duplicates by itself, but the code I posted should. Did you try it? Does something about it not work?

Comment: Well I got some errors trying to run the code, I managed to fix some of them but without succes. So I used your code as inspiration/guideline. I updated my question wth the new code + explaination.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.

The `lastLogonTimeStamp` attribute is replicated to all DC's, but is only updated during logon if the existing value is 14 or more days old.

The `lastLogon` attribute is updated at every logon, but is not replicated. You'll need to query all DC's to get an accurate lastLogon value for each user.

I (for better or worse) tend to do this...

```
$stuff = $(net user $env:username /domain | select-string 'Last logon*').ToString()
$label, $login_date = [regex]::split($stuff, '\s{5,}')
$login_date
```

It's quick and dirty.