# Get-ADUser across domains - Help needed

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following [code](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Last-Logon-for-Users-c8e3eab2#content):

```
$FilePath_Prefix = "C:\temp\UserLastLogon-" 

function Msg ($Txt="") { 
    Write-Host "$([DateTime]::Now)    $Txt" 
} 

#Cycle each DC and gather user account lastlogon attributes 
$List = @() #Define Array 
(Get-ADDomain).ReplicaDirectoryServers | Sort | % { 
    $DC = $_ 
    Msg "Reading $DC" 
    $List += Get-ADUser -Server $_ -Filter "samaccountname -like '*'" -Properties LastLogon |
             Select samaccountname, lastlogon, @{n='DC';e={$DC}} 
} 

Msg "Sorting for most recent lastlogon" 

$LatestLogOn = @() #Define Array 
$List | Group-Object -Property samaccountname | % { 
    $LatestLogOn += ($_.Group | Sort -prop lastlogon -Descending)[0] 
} 

$List.Clear() 
$FileName = "$FilePath_Prefix$([DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")).csv" 

try { 
    $LatestLogOn |
        Select samaccountname, lastlogon,
            @{n='lastlogondatetime';e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastlogon)}}, DC |
        Export-CSV -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Force
    Msg "Exported results. $FileName" 
} catch { 
    Msg "Export Failed. $FileName" 
}
```

I use it to interrogate AD Users for most up-to-date lastLogon information across all my domains. It works, and it works really fast.

Now, I need to get more details into my output, such as `givenName` and `Surname` lets say.
What would be the best approach to achieve this, because I don't want to interrogate redundantly all my DC's for those kind of attributes.

My idea here, is to create another array with `Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties givenName, surname, etc..etc` and then bind together the two arrays. And I don't seem to get it right. Could someone help, or point me in the right direction to achieve this task.

Comment: Why aren't you just looking at the `PDC Emulator`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Because LastLogon is not replicated between DCs.  It's only updated on the most recently authenticated server and that's where it stays.  The value that is replicated, LastLogonTimestamp, is only updated if LastLogon and LastLogonTimestamp are more than 14 days apart.  The design of AD is not intended look for stale accounts less than about a month old.  See also: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fetch all the last logon information and save it into a hash table, which is designed for fast lookups.  I'd try something like this:

```
$FileName = 'C:\temp\UserLastLogon-{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.csv' -f [DateTime]::Now
$DCs = (Get-ADDomain).ReplicaDirectoryServers | Sort-Object

# This *may* be more semantically accurate; I don't remember how it works with multiple domains
# $DC = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName | Sort-Object

# Create the hash table
$UserLogonInfo = @{}

foreach ($DC in $DCs) {
    Write-Host "Reading logon data from $DC..."
    # Fetch all users that have a LastLogon value from the current DC
    # We specify LastLogon>=1 because some users that never log on have LastLogon of
    # 0 or null, both of which would show up as Jan 1, 1601.
    Get-ADUser -Server $DC -LDAPFilter '(LastLogon>=1)' -Properties LastLogon | ForEach-Object {
        if (!$UserLogonInfo.ContainsKey($_.DistinguishedName)) {
            # If the accountname doesn't exist, add it
            $UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName] = @{
                LastLogon         = $_.LastLogon
                LastLogonDateTime = ([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon))
                LastLogonDC       = $DC
            }
        }
        elseif (($UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName].LastLogon -lt $_.LastLogon)) {
            # If the account name exists, update it if it's more recent
            $UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName] = @{
                LastLogon         = $_.LastLogon
                LastLogonDateTime = ([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon))
                LastLogonDC       = $DC
            }
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Fetching user data..."
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogon, givenName, surname |
    Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, givenName, surname,
        @{n='LastLogonDateTime';e={$UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName].LastLogonDateTime}},
        @{n='LastLogonDC';e={$UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName].LastLogonDC}} |
    Export-CSV -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

If an account has a blank `LastLogonDateTime` and blank `LastLogonDC`, then that account has never logged on.

It's more correct to use `DistinguishedName` instead of `SamAccountName` as the key for the `$UserLogonInfo` hash table, and that is essentially a required change if you are querying multiple domains at once.  Note that I do mean *multiple domains* and not merely *multiple domain controllers in the same domain* (which is what I believe you're actually doing in spite of the question title).

This whole process on my domain with 3 DCs and ~10,000 users takes about 15 seconds.

Note that there are a *ton* of ways that LastLogon can be inaccurate. It can be updated without a full logon or without an interactive logon and some logons won't force an update of the field. If you really want to track logons, you should use security auditing for logon events.

---

Edit:

When we populate `$UserLogonInfo` we're fetching all accounts except for accounts that either don't have a `LogonDate` attribute at all or when that attribute is 0 or null.  Each of those indicate that there has been no login. So, we know that any user that isn't in the `$UserLogonInfo` hash table has never logged in.

If you want to use some special value for when a user account has never logged on, you should just use an `if` statement and check to see if the user is in the `$UserLogonInfo` hash table:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogon, givenName, surname |
    Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, givenName, surname,
        @{n = 'LastLogonDateTime'; e = {if ($UserLogonInfo.ContainsKey($_.DistinguishedName)) { $UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName].LastLogonDateTime } else { 'Never' }}},
        @{n = 'LastLogonDC'; e = {if ($UserLogonInfo.ContainsKey($_.DistinguishedName)) { $UserLogonInfo[$_.DistinguishedName].LastLogonDC } else { 'N/A' }}} |
        Export-CSV -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. It sheds some light on how to achieve my goal. Yes, you assumption that I only query multiple domain controllers within one domain is correct. I’ve measured your solution and found that it is actually way faster than the example I had from Microsoft. Kudos for this! Now I can add as many attributes I need in a very simple manner to the end result. One question though: how can I tag the UA’s which have never logged on on any dc within this routine? If I remove the filter on ‘LastLogon >1’ then the script takes much longer to finish..

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're actually asking your DCs for that data as it's returned by default. So the only thing to add is

```
, givenName, surname
```

to your `Select-Object`. Check this by running

```
Get-AdUser yourLogin -Properties LastLogon
```

You'll receive the following properties in your output: `DistinguishedName` `Enabled` `GivenName` `LastLogon`
`Name`
`ObjectClass`
`ObjectGUID`
`SamAccountName`
`SID`
`Surname`
`UserPrincipalName`

So the only thing you lose will be some memory. The alternative approach would be to create another array using

```
$names = Get-ADuser -Filter * | Select-Object SamAccountName, givenName, surname
```

and then match the date based on `SamAccountName` like this:

```
$LatestLogOn = @() #Define Array 
$List | Group-Object -Property samaccountname | % { 
    $t = ($_.Group | Sort -prop lastlogon -Descending)[0]
    $n = $names | Where-Object samaccountname -eq $t.samaccountname 
    $LatestLogOn += $t | select *, @{n="givenName";e={$n.givenName}}, @{n="surname";e={$n.surname}}
}
```